# The Widget or components(such as Rating Bar) from the Palette are not visible on the design view or the blueprint on the Android Studio

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am a beginner so this question may be stupid for others.
You can see that I have Already selected the Rating bar but it is neither visible on the Design view and nor on the blueprint.I am done with restarting the project but still nothing

[image: The Android Studio Screenshot]

Here is the screenshot of my code window --> [Click here to see the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFi9i.png)

Comment: what happens when you click a meander with an `x` and then press magic wand in the toolbar?

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo I dont know how to do it could you explain more about it.

Comment: icons am referring to are next to text 8dp in your image one have a red x and another looks like a magic wand. 

Here is an image of a magic wand to give you an idea of the icon: https://4vector.com/free-vector/magic-wand-101665

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo I did this but still not working

Comment: can you switch to text (see the bottom tab) from design and update the post with code?

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo ok

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo Please have a look to the code and solve this problem.

Comment: edit post and add code as text not image